# Webpack - sass loader cannot find images

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, sass-loader

The `sass loader` doc says: `"If you're just generating CSS without passing it to the css-loader, it must be relative to your web root"`.
So i did as it tells, I have my `index.html` in my `project root`, then I'm trying to load an `image` from my `scss` file.
Now I have 2 errors: 1) from `Chrome's console`: `Cannot find module "./img/header.jpg"`. 2) from my `terminal`:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./public/css/header.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./img/header.jpg in C:\Web-Development\React\Portfolio\public\css
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./public/css/header.scss 6:64-91
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './main.jsx',
    output: {
        filename: './public/js/build/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
              test: /\.jsx?$/,
              exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
              loader: 'babel',
              query: {
                  presets: ['react', 'es2015']
              }
          },
          {
              test: /\.scss$/,
              loaders: ["style", "css", "sass", "resolve-url"]
          },
          {
            test: /\.jpg$/,
            loader: "file?name=[path][name].[ext]"
          }
        ]
    }
};
```

If I see my code, I can clearly see that my css lives inside `<head>` so I've pointed my image's path to my root, as documentation says, but still can't fix it.

**UPDATE:**
I've installed `file-loader` and followed the instructions, now I get this error in console: `GET http://localhost:3000/public/img/header.jpg 404 (Not Found) - jquery.js:9119`

Comment: The issue could be with the bower_components directory maybe?
I had a similar issue here with fonts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33733370/webpack-cannot-load-fonts-from-bower-using-css-scss

Comment: I am facing similar issue. I have installed url-loader, file-loader but still I am gietting an error http://localhost:8080/97e0c94dad5b497783b1400e27dfdcbb.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I've uploaded this [webpack extremly basic configuration](https://github.com/b82/webpack-basic-starter) to start my projects, I hope it can help everyone who had this problem. Suggestions are all welcome of course.

Comment: When you want to link to external resources, please add the relevant part here on Stackoverflow since the link could be unavailable.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can see you are actually using the css loader ( `"style", "css", "sass", "resolve-url"` ) (the "css" part is the "css-loader")

In your sass file(s) you should link to the images using a relative path from the sass file you are editing.

```
styles
 - somefile.scss
 - another.scss
images
 - someImage.jpg
```

in somefile.scss, you should link to your image like this:

`background-image: url("../images/someImage.jpg);`

Do note, that if you want webpack to move those images to your distribution folder (if you are using a system like this) that you will need something like `file-loader` to copy those files over.

Comment: I've tried to point my scss file to my img folder doing url( ../img/header.jpg) but this time I get this other error: ERROR in ./public/img/header.jpg
Module parse failed: C:\Web-Development\React\Portfolio\public\img\header.jpg Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./public/css/header.scss 6:64-92

Comment: That's why you need the file-loader. Just like for your scss files, you need to specify a test and a loader (in this case file-loader)

Comment: Ok, I've added `{ test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file?name=[path][name].[ext]" }` in my webpack.config.js but now in Chrome's console i get a different error: `GET http://localhost:3000/public/img/header.jpg 404 (Not Found) - jquery.js:9119`. I'm sorry for all these questions, I've just started in these days to use all of these tools

Comment: @LucaMormile great question and it seems like Wout has addressed the original problem? If so, marking it "accepted" is helpful for the community :)

Comment: Hi @Ben, apologies cause right now I can't try Wout's answer (no time to work on ReactJS :(( ), but I've just wrote an answer with a link to my webpack configuration file that solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ignore-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-loader) if your images are already in the place where you need them. file-loader will copy the files to your output folder.