# Laravel home(~) SCSS paths not resolving correctly

Tags: php, laravel, css, webpack, sass

Ive tried a number of solutions and have not found anything that works.

My base directory for all files is localhost/manpower

I put this in my webpack...
    let mix = require('laravel-mix');

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
|
 */
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/assets/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/assets/css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/header.scss', 'public/assets/css')
    .version();
```

When I use the ~ for the home, the processing of the CSS just removes the ~

mix.setPublicPath('manpower/public');

Just creates a directory under the existing file structure and puts the files in that.  Unfortunately this popular solution does not change the output of the final CSS.

No mater what I try, I can't get it to add 'manpower' to the URL's I put in the SCCS!

Answer (score 0):

Posting my config to help you, I think that you forgot to define the alias, I have my config in two files to help the IDE (PHPStorm) recognize the ~
(solution from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50159420/5458355)

// webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require('lodash-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {

resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
  alias: {
    '~': path.resolve(__dirname, './resources/assets/js')
  }
},
output: {
  path: process.env.MIX_APP_URL, <--- var from .env
  publicPath: '/Socse.GST/public/',
  chunkFilename: 'dist/js/chunk.[name].js'
 } 
}
```

// webpack.mix.js

```
const path = require('path')
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
const webpack = require('webpack')

mix
 .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/dist/js')
 .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/dist/css')
 .styles([
   'resources/assets/sass/fa/css/fontawesome-all.css',
   'public/css/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css',
   'public/css/inspinia.css',
   'node_modules/vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css'
 ], 'public/dist/css/all.css')

 .sourceMaps()
 //.disableNotifications()

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix.version()
}

mix.webpackConfig({
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     $: 'jquery',
     jQuery: 'jquery',
     'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
     Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
],
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
      alias: {
       '~': path.join(__dirname, './resources/assets/js')
      }
    },
output: {
   chunkFilename: 'dist/js/chunk.[name].[chunkhash].js',
   path: process.env.MIX_APP_URL,
   publicPath: '/wms/public/'
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but this does not resolve the issue Im facing.  I did a fresh install of laravel on this machine.  Added the SCCS to the path.  Changed the End value to the new install.  And ran the 'npm run dev'.  Still I get "/" as the root path...  Everything I do effect the path the computer looks at and not the path assigned to the final css.

Ive currently spent the last 4 hours researching this.  The only solutions offered that I can find do not solve the problem.  Ive tried everything.

Comment: do you have the alias in the resolve object? can you post your webpack.mix entirely and your scss file ?

Answer (score 0):

New version

```
    const path = require('path');
    const mix = require('laravel-mix');
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    mix
        .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'assets/js')
        .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'assets/css')
        .sass('resources/assets/sass/header.scss', 'assets/css')
        .version()
        .options({
            processCssUrls: true
        });
    if (mix.inProduction()) {
        mix.version()
    }

    mix.webpackConfig({
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '~': path.join(__dirname, './resources/')
            }
        },
        output: {
            chunkFilename: 'dist/js/chunk.[name].[chunkhash].js',
            path: process.env.MIX_APP_URL,
            publicPath: '/public/'
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure this is a problem with the webpack.config.js

Ive been able to resolve some of the issues but the error remains.

```
/**
 * As our first step, we'll pull in the user's webpack.mix.js
 * file. Based on what the user requests in that file,
 * a generic config object will be constructed for us.
 */
let mix = require('../index');

let ComponentFactory = require('../components/ComponentFactory');

new ComponentFactory().installAll();

require(Mix.paths.mix());

/**
 * Just in case the user needs to hook into this point
 * in the build process, we'll make an announcement.
 */

Mix.dispatch('init', Mix);

/**
 * Now that we know which build tasks are required by the
 * user, we can dynamically create a configuration object
 * for Webpack. And that's all there is to it. Simple!
 */

let WebpackConfig = require('../src/builder/WebpackConfig');

//module.exports = new WebpackConfig().build();



const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
        alias: {
            '~': path.resolve(__dirname, './resources/assets/js')
        },
    },
    output: {
        path: process.env.MIX_APP_URL,
    publicPath: '/manpower/public/',
    chunkFilename: 'dist/js/chunk.[name].js'
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to provide your version of mix and sass-loader (there is a bug in old sass-loader that does not work with tilde).   Also, please do not post comment as update, it causes confusions in your question.

Generally, avoid using tilde; instead, use relative path.  You want to look at this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33972875/2188545

Even without all the confusing comments, tilde is confusing when use in url, especially when your browser path `manpower/` is not a simple root `/` path.   Don't get me wrong, tilde is fine with css import as it is generally resolve during compilation; just more confusing when use in `url`.  Also, please use quote around your css url.

Comment: I appreciate that.  But I can't get this path to work.  

From what I can tell, this is a windows issue.  What I can tell, laravel hates windows 10.

It's kinda crazy.  I set the "setPublicPath" to 'manpower/public' and the assets get put in c:/wamp64/www/

I see others have this issue... https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/960

As far as I can tell, they say "path.normalize" works for them.  Everything I try doesn't work.  Ive tried the options publicPath, .setPublicPath and many other things.  From what I can tell some crazy logic at work.

Comment: I add a path, "manpower" and I get c:\wamp64\www\manpower\manpower\

I remove the path and I get c:\wamp64\www

Comment: And my output is coming out as /images

Comment: Ive gotten it to output to the right directory.  But Ive never gotten it to output /manpower as the home.  As far as I can tell, this is unusable with windows 10 and should be marked as such.

Comment: Ive spent 10 hours trying to get this to output.  Im abandoning Windows and moving to a linux machine.  I just can't get it to work on Windows. Didn't know laravel was linux only. :(